# How to implement SimpleTest in Kohana

Tags: php, unit-testing, kohana, simpletest

My boss assigned me to learn how to use Kohana and implement simple test in that. We would like to use it as our framework for future projects.

Being new to both [KohanaPHP](http://kohanaphp.com/) and [SimpleTest](http://simpletest.sf.net/), I can't figure out how to do even the simplest test of my helpers. I can't even find a single step-by-step tutorial on how to attach SimpleTest to Kohana.

Anyone here have an idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've created a SimpleTest_controller in Kohana

and it gets the test from a directory tests

```
define ( 'SIMPLE_TEST', '../tools/simpletest/');
require_once(SIMPLE_TEST . 'unit_tester.php');
require_once(SIMPLE_TEST . 'reporter.php');
require_once( SIMPLE_TEST . 'mock_objects.php');

class SimpleTest_Controller extends Controller {
  function index() {
    $this->runall();
  }

  function runall() {
    $sDir = '../tests/';
    $rDir = opendir( $sDir );

    while ( $sFile = readdir( $rDir ) ) {
      if ( $sFile != '.' && $sFile != '..' ) {
        $this->run( $sFile );
      }
    }
  }

  function run ( $sTests ) {
    $sDir = '../tests/' . $sTests .'/';
    $rDir = opendir( $sDir );
    $test = new GroupTest( $sTests );

    while ( $sFile = readdir( $rDir ) ) {
      if ( $sFile != '.' && $sFile != '..' && !preg_match('/~\d+~/', $sFile) ) {
        include_once($sDir . $sFile);
        $test->addTestCase( substr($sFile, 0, -4 ) );
      }
    }

    $test->run( new HtmlReporter() );
  }
}
```

you can call `domain.com/simpletest` to run all
or you can call `domain.com/simpletest/run/account` if you have a accountfolder in your testfolder